# "The questions are not final, and we don't want them released publicly before we go live"

Tags: discussion, email

From a recent SO e-mail:

> The questions are not final, and we don't want them released publicly before we go live

Assuming nothing in this statement is superfluous, isn't it contradictory?

As in, if the questions will change prior to go-live, then public release of the current question drafts shouldn't be a problem because it won't actually divulge any of the final content.

Or if the questions shouldn't be released publicly before go-live because the final content must remain secret and releasing the current questions would divulge that secret, then doesn't that mean they're already effectively final?

Or if the concern is that the draft content will merely look sloppy/embarrassing (or expose information about the differences between draft and final content), then shouldn't the request be to not release the draft questions ever, before or after go-live?

Is there a sensible, non-contradictory relationship that can exist between "the questions are not final" and "we don't want them released publicly before we go live" where *both* propositions are required?

Answer (score 1):

This is very usual, and not contradictory at all imo.

When creating a draft of anything, e.g. a book, movie, game, etc. it's usual to keep the details confidential, and when getting responses from a pilot group, it's also usual to keep it confidential.

There may be many reasons for it, such as that you don't want the public discussing shortcomings you're aware of and going to address in the final version, because you might not want to ruin anticipation, because you're A-B testing and want the subjects to be unaware of that fact, because you want competitors to be unaware of new changes, etc.

<sub>some of these are less applicable to this specific mail, but you get the point</sub>